# JQuery element + class + selector syntax

Tags: jquery

I would like to select the last visible `<span class="delimiter'></span>` element.  The following syntax does not work:

```
$('span.delimiter:visible');
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: maybe try `$('.delimiter').is(':visible')`?

Comment: "Works" for me: http://jsfiddle.net/tKSS4/ Care to elaborate what the problem is?

Comment: @FelixKling: Here's your fiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/tKSS4/2/ with probably the solution to Jack's problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('span.delimiter:visible:last');
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$('span.delimiter:visible:last')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span.delimiter:visible:last')
```

---

```
$('span.delimiter:visible').last();
```

---

```
$("span.delimiter").filter(function() {
    return $(this).is(":visible");
}).last();
```

Comment: sometimes I think long selectors look very confusing. And hard to read if you are just scrolling throw your code. Thats why.